# How does NiFi handle throttling or queuing when too much work is scheduled?

Tags: multithreading, performance, apache-nifi

If I schedule NiFi to run X-number of processes at the exact same time, knowing that my instance is incapable of *actually* running that number all at once, how does NiFi handle that scenario?

Will it actually kick of X-number of threads and let them compete for CPU? Or does it have some inherent ability to throttle so that work outside of some limit is queued until a resource is free?

I'm asking because I'm certain I will run into this scenario, and if it actually kicks off the specified number of threads the instance is likely to crash. So if it can't queue then I'll need to build some external code to handle the throttling.

Comment: The parameters on the "Scheduling" tab on each processor could be used for throttling.

Comment: But do they throttle across flows? It looks like those settings only affect a single process. I need to ensure the system doesn't bog even if users setup inefficient scheduling, like kicking off all flows at the top of each hour.

Comment: There is a configurable setting in `nifi.properties` for *max concurrent threads*, so you can limit the total number of threads available to NiFi processes; I believe the default is 10. This should prevent your instance from overloading the hardware.

Comment: See also [concurrent and parallel execution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46553432/70465).

Comment: Awesome. That's what I was looking for.